# Is the colour mixer a feature that is not available in CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cs6

I am following along with a tutorial and using Illustrator CS6 version. It mentions a colour mixer but I can't find it. I am wondering if this feature is for later versions? Also if there is an alternative to this in the CS6 version?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no Properties Panel** in Illustrator CS6. 
Therefore there is **no Color Mixer** option in Illustrator CS6.

However, Illustrator CS6 **does** have the **Color Guide** panel, which is similar. 
Simply choose `Window > Color Guide` to view the panel.

[image]

If you are following tutorials, it's wise to be aware that if the tutorial author is utilizing a newer version of the application, there may be *many* things which are not present in legacy application versions. There isn't always an equivalent to a new feature in older versions.

Comment: thank you! Yes I do realise that it may be very frustrating to follow this tutorial now as I will have to stop and start quite a lot I may need to find another tutorial

Comment: @MarianD if you don't ping user3413128 in the comment (like I've pinged you here) it's unlikely they'll ever see the comment. -- I do appreciate the comment `:)`

Comment: @user3413128, welcome to Graphic Design! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Scott, I think (or I thank) that OP of question automatically obtains notifications about *all* comments, but maybe I'm wrong. Nevertheless, I followed your advice and rewrote that comment, now pinging the OP in it.

Comment: @MarianD could be.. but I believe it's only comments on the question, not answers. I understood things that only I get notified on comments on *my answer*. Like I did for this. It could have changed recently and I'd be unaware.... so... you may be right `:)`